# Matplotlib - using imshow for transformed coordinates within meshgrid arrays

Tags: python, matplotlib, imshow

I am using a python script to calculate the stress fields (Z meshgrid array) for a defects within a metal. In order to do this, I have to transform the X and Y meshgrids (xtrans and ytrans). I am then using imshow to plot colour along with the contour lines. The problem I am having is that imshow assumes that the Z array contains values at points running linearly between two ranges. E.g it assumes Z[0,:] are the values in the Y direction that go from -5, -4,-3, -2...3, 4, 5 say. After the coordinates are transformed Y isn't spaced linearly between -5 and 5.

Is there a way to use imshow or a function like it, that has  Xtrans, and ytrans meshgrids as input parameters?

```
import numpy as np
import scipy
import matcompat
from scipy.integrate import quad, nquad
from CalcQSB import CalcQSB
from dislstress import dislstress
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import cm
import scipy.interpolate
```

...

```
# evaluate over a grid
num = 50
npts =200
xi, yi = np.linspace(-num, num, npts), np.linspace(-num, num, npts)

X, Y = np.meshgrid(xi, yi)
Z = np.zeros(matcompat.size(X))

xtrans, ytrans = np.meshgrid(xi, yi)
```

... more code for determining correct values in the Z array.

```
v = np.linspace(np.amin(Z), np.amax(Z), 15, endpoint=True)

plt.imshow(Z, vmin=np.amin(Z), vmax=np.amax(Z), origin='lower',
       extent=[np.amin(xtrans), np.amax(xtrans), np.amin(ytrans), np.amax(ytrans)])
plt.colorbar(ticks=v)

CS = plt.contour(xtrans, ytrans, Z,20,colors='k')

plt.show()
```

If someone can help, I would be most grateful.

Thanks

Luke

Comment: Just to check I understand correctly: you want to know how to plot a mesh where the spacing of the nodes is non-linear? Have you looked at `pcolormesh`?

Comment: Thanks @tom, I just tried using pcolormesh and that seemed to resolve the problem. The resolution isn't very good though so I will have to look at improving it. Thanks, Luke